# Rails Tutorial Help on Chapter 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have run into 4 errors on section 9.2.2.

## Errors

> ERROR["test_unsuccessful_edit", UsersEditTest, 2015-11-05 04:35:59 -0600]
>    test_unsuccessful_edit#UsersEditTest (1446719759.23s)
>   NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `correct_user?' for #<UsersController:0x007fcdf48ad378>
>               app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in`correct_user'
>               test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'
>           app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in`correct_user'
>           test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:10:in `block in '
>
> ERROR["test_successful_edit", UsersEditTest, 2015-11-05 04:35:59 -0600]
>    test_successful_edit#UsersEditTest (1446719759.28s)
>   NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `correct_user?' for #<UsersController:0x007fcdefcea198>
>               app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in`correct_user'
>               test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'
>           app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in`correct_user'
>           test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:21:in `block in '
>
> ERROR["test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", UsersControllerTest, 2015-11-05 04:35:59 -0600]
>    test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (1446719759.42s)
>   NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `correct_user?' for #<UsersController:0x007fcdf529f778>
>               app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in`correct_user'
>               test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:29:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
>           app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in`correct_user'
>           test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:29:in `block in '
>
> ERROR["test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user", UsersControllerTest, 2015-11-05 04:35:59 -0600]
>    test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user#UsersControllerTest (1446719759.44s)
>   NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `correct_user?' for #<UsersController:0x007fcdf531e118>
>               app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in`correct_user'
>               test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
>           app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58:in`correct_user'
>           test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:36:in `block in '

32/32: [======================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.70355s
32 tests, 64 assertions, 0 failures, 4 errors, 0 skips

## Users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
                                    :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before Filters

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless correct_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

## User_controller_test

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

    def setup
        @user           = users(:michael)
        @other_user = users(:archer)
    end

    test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should redirect edit when logged in" do
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when not logged in" do
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
end
```

## users.yml

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

## users_edit_test

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "unsuccessful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name:  "",
                                    email: "foo@invalid",
                                    password:              "foo",
                                    password_confirmation: "bar" }
    assert_template 'users/edit'    
  end

  test "successful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    name  = "Foo Bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name:  name,
                                    email: email,
                                    password:              "",
                                    password_confirmation: "" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    assert_equal name,  @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email
    end
end
```

I think that is all that would be needed to help. I have been struggling for some time now. This is my first post, sorry if it isn't easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## correct_user? isn't defined anywhere.

`redirect_to(root_url) unless correct_user?(@user)`

Rails's syntactic sugar is going to look for a model flag correct_user or a boolean-returning function #correct_user? getter. I'm assuming that you're trying to validate that an update request from a user actually belongs to the correct user. To do this you must have current_user stored in a session, and then check the request param[:id] == current_user.id